# Reuse nginx configuration across environments

Tags: nginx

Consider a php application for which I have a stage and a production environment. There would be 2 separate configuration files like so:

stage config:

```
server {

  root /var/www;
  server_name stage.mysite.org;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files       $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;
  }

}
```

prod config:

```
server {

  root /var/www;
  server_name mysite.org;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files       $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;
  }

}
```

The only difference between the 2 config files is the server_name. Now, in the interest of DRY, what I'd like to do is checkin a single nginx configuration file, that is shared by both environments.

I realize I could just include both urls in server_name, but that's a bit weird since I really only want one per environment. Could I somehow extract the server_name into a config.json file or something that includes the proper url. Something like this:

Universal nginx config:

```
server {

  root /var/www;
  server_name ${hostname};

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files       $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;
  }

}
```

stage.config.json

```
{
  "hostname": "stage.mysite.org"
}
```

Thanks!